# Newtonsoft.JSON, Deserialize different JSON fields that similar into single type, but will have different deserialized object field

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON that have fields that more or less look like this

```
{
    "Photos" : 
    [
        {
            "file_id" : "Some value",
            "type" : "Some certain value",
            /*'Photo's specific fields*/
        },
        {
            "file_id" : "Some value",
            "type" : "Some certain value",
            /*'Photo's specific fields*/
        },
        {
            "file_id" : "Some value",
            "type" : "Some certain value",
            /*'Photo's specific fields*/
        }

    ],
    "Document" : 
    {
        "file_id" : "Some value",
        "type" : "Some certain value",
        /*'Document's specific fields*/
    },
    "Video" : 
    {
        "file_id" : "Some value",
        "type" : "Some certain value",
        /*'Video's specific fields*/
    },
}
```

Where the whole JSON will be deserialized into this class

```
public class APIResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Photos")]
    public List<APIFile> Photos;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Document")]
    public APIFile Document;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Video")]
    public APIFile Video;
}
```

Where `APIFile` is a class that is the 'Target Type' for each of that JSON fields deserialization, it looks like this

```
public class APIFile
{
    public enum FileMIME
    {
        // Some already specified enum values
    }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "file_id")]
    public string FileID;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string FileType;
    [JsonIgnore()]
    public FileMIME MIMEType;
}
```

As you can see, those three fields in the JSON share some common fields, `file_id` and `type`, where `Photos` is collection of certain type that also share the same common fields.

The problem is, how can i deserialize each of them but seting up the `MIMEType` field respective to the deserialized field ? preferably without using `JsonConverter` or adding extra class

For example, when it's deserializing JSON field `Document` then the field `Document` in the `APIResponse` object will be created
with `MIMEType` field having value `MIMEType.Document`

Comment: Why not make `APIFile` be an abstract base class, and subclass it as `APIPhoto`, `APIVideo`, `APIDocument` and so on?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the number of class i have to make to fulfill this JSON schema requirement, and i don't really need the rest of the fields from each of type

It's Telegram Bot API BTW, try to visit the API page, see the "Available Types", it's humongous and very - very nested (at least for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setters with backing private fields:

```
    public enum FileMIME
    {
        Document,
        Photos,
        Video       
    }

    public class APIResponse
    {
        private List<APIFile> _photos;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Photos")]
        public List<APIFile> Photos
        {
            get { return _photos; }
            set {   _photos = value;
                    foreach(var photo in _photos)
                    {
                        photo.MIMEType = FileMIME.Photos;
                    }
                }
        }

        private APIFile _document;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Document")]
        public APIFile Document
        {
            get { return _document; }
            set { _document = value; _document.MIMEType = FileMIME.Document; }
        }

        private APIFile _video;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Video")]
        public APIFile Video
        {
            get { return _video; }
            set { _video = value; _video.MIMEType = FileMIME.Video; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see, never thought `set`ter can be used like this, but to bad it requires backing value. Still, regardless i didn't have to create separate converter

Comment: another one though, can i do something like `value.MIME = MIMEType.Video` then do `_video = value` or i can only do it only to the backing value after the `value` assigment to the back-val ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of the APIFile class. Then you can add the FileMIME to each dictionary before returning the response.